# access array element inside array

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am having data like this:

```
{"results":[{"id":65,"title":"rap god 3","rating":"9.0","genres":[{"id":14,"name":"New Genre"},{"id":550,"name":"bollywood"}]},{"id":68,"title":"bol naa","rating":"3.1","genres":[{"id":45,"name":"LOLOL"}]},{"id":69,"title":"rap god 2","rating":"2.0","genres":[]},{"id":70,"title":"last track","rating":"3.0","genres":[{"id":17,"name":"horror"}]},{"id":71,"title":"animalsssss","rating":"4.0","genres":[{"id":22,"name":"lol"}]},{"id":72,"title":"sanam re sanam re","rating":"3.0","genres":[{"id":10,"name":"surf excel"},{"id":16,"name":"Trancee"},{"id":21,"name":"indie-rockk"}]},{"id":73,"title":"testing data for genre","rating":"3.0","genres":[]},{"id":74,"title":"testing data for multi genre","rating":"2.2","genres":[]},{"id":75,"title":"hip hop","rating":"5.0","genres":[{"id":10,"name":"surf excel"}]},{"id":76,"title":"animals","rating":"3.0","genres":[{"id":12,"name":"bollywood"},{"id":17,"name":"horror"},{"id":18,"name":"india jeet bhai ppp"},{"id":21,"name":"indie-rockk"}]},{"id":77,"title":"bolly","rating":"2.0","genres":[{"id":21,"name":"indie-rockk"}]},{"id":78,"title":"sass","rating":"3.0","genres":[{"id":20,"name":"classical"}]},{"id":79,"title":"done","rating":"5.0","genres":[{"id":16,"name":"Trancee"}]},{"id":80,"title":"baskar","rating":"2.0","genres":[]},{"id":81,"title":"sass","rating":"5.0","genres":[{"id":22,"name":"lol"}]},{"id":82,"title":"ano 2","rating":"3.0","genres":[]},{"id":83,"title":"sanam re sanam re","rating":"3.2","genres":[]},{"id":84,"title":"sanam re sanam re","rating":"3.2","genres":[]},{"id":85,"title":"kuch na kho","rating":"4.0","genres":[{"id":10,"name":"surf excel"}]},{"id":86,"title":"sat sat","rating":"4.0","genres":[]}]}
```

Now I want to print the title ,genre and rating. The rating should be of the form of stars. Data having more than one genre, genre should be separated by | symbol. Example: rap god [New Genre|bollywood] rating as stars.

I have tried this but not getting the genre printed

```
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of tracks|filter:term">
      {{item.title}}
      <div *ngFor="let genre of tracks.genres">
      {{tracks.genres?.tracks.genres.name}}
    </div>
```

I am using angular 2 ..please help..

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not come with `filter pipe`. And assume your `tracks` mean `results` like below:

```
const data = {
  "results": ...
}
```

and

```
tracks = data.results
```

now, your template look like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of tracks">
  {{item.title}}
  [
  <span *ngFor="let genre of item.genres; let lst = last;">
    {{genre?.name}}
    <ng-container *ngIf="!lst"><!-- if not last item, print | -->
      |
    </ng-container>
  </span>
  ]
</li>
```

demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/noaAJVEJqsz0FZivv7iz?p=preview

Comment: i am just getting [] (empty) to right of  the name. My Trackmodel.ts file is:
export class TrackModel{
  id:number;
  title:string;
  rating:number;
  genre:any;

}

Comment: because your have empty genres in this data `{  
         "id":69,
         "title":"rap god 2",
         "rating":"2.0",
         "genres":[  

         ]
      },`

Comment: For every data i am getting the same result sir.{"id":65,"title":"rap god 3","rating":"9.0","genres":[{"id":14,"name":"New Genre"},{"id":550,"name":"bollywood"}]....expected output is rap god [NewGenre | bollywood]

Comment: I am getting blank genre for each data

Comment: wait a minute.!